# need help for combine sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to some help regarding below query

```
select * from customers where orderdate < 01-09-2010 

select * from order where purchasedate < 01-09-2010
```

I want to combine above querys into one.

As a result I want to get customers who have not placed order after 01-09-2010.

Comment: It will be good if you post the  customer and Order table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need join key in two table.
for example customer's name, query will be like this.

```
select a.*, b.*
from customers a, order b
where a.name = b.customer_name
and a.orderdate < 01-09-2010
and b.purchasedate > 01-09-2010
```

Comment: I think, to keep data in same columns from both tables as I suspect the question requires you would need a UNION

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.*
from customers c 
left join order o on c.name = o.customer_name and o.purchasedate > 01-09-2010
where c.orderdate < 01-09-2010
```